# AWS Quicksight: Show actual values instead of aggregate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, data-lake

I want to use AWS Quicksight to show the values over time of a data set I have in S3 data lake. It looks like this:
[image: Data overview]

Where 0 is for example standing still, 1 is walking, and 2 is running.

So now in Quicksight, I created an analysis. Als fields I selected time and value, and I added a filter for a specific device ID. The only problem is I can only show aggregates of the data, not the actual value. I can show the Sum of the value, or the Average, but that doesnt help me with displaying when a person is running. Is there some way I can achieve this?

[image: Graph]